# wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'VENTAS_MAYOR'

Tags: oracle, plsql

Buenas tengo este procedimiento con el parámetro FECHITA tipo DATE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VENTAS_MAYOR (FECHITA IN DATE)

IS
V_FECHA DATE;
V_CANTIDAD NUMBER;
V_DESCRIPCION VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
SELECT 
   A.FECHAEMISION_BOL,
   B.CANTIDAD,
   C.DESCRIPCION

INTO 
 V_FECHA,
 V_CANTIDAD,
 V_DESCRIPCION

FROM BOLETA A JOIN DETALLE B ON (A.COD_BOLETA = B.COD_DETALLE)
          JOIN PRODUCTO C ON (B.COD_DETALLE = C.CODPRODUCTO)
WHERE A.FECHAEMISION_BOL = FECHITA
ORDER BY CANTIDAD DESC;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_CANTIDAD || V_DESCRIPCION);
END VENTAS_MAYOR;
```

Pero a la hora de ejecutar la función con un parámetro me da el error de la cantidad de argumentos...

```
--CONSULTAR PO PARAMETROS
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
EXECUTE VENTAS_MAYOR(05/2019);
```

Ayuda por favor !

Comment: Bienvenido DIEGO IGNACIO a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Es correcta la forma en que estás indicando la fecha? ¿no sería así: `EXECUTE VENTAS_MAYOR('2019/05/01');`?

Comment: Estoy totalmente deacuerdo con Patricio, los SP de oracle por lo regular si no es que siempre deben recibir los parametros date con el cormato 'YYYY-MM-DD'